# How to display record into drop down Menu

Tags: linq, combobox

I have a problem is it possible to or is there any code when I open the form , the field example : i have a 4 fields namely
 id, 
name, 
age 
gender

i want to display the field "name" into the combo box so if the record is more than 1 automatically it adds the items in the combo box.

hope someone can understand my problem newbie in using LINQ..

thank you

Comment: i  have sample code but this is the result.. sad to say it gets the column name in the combo box..please see attachment

Comment: Please post some code what you have tried yet